# How can I replace the final price with a string instead of a number?

Tags: plugin, magento2.4

I have some products where the company is still trying to figure out the price. Those products are currently set to 0.
I was the words "Call for pricing" to show up if a price is 0.
I wrote a plugin for afterGetPrice which looks like this

```
<?php

namespace Company\companyplugins\Plugins;

use \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;

class CallIfZero
{
    /**
     * @param Product $product
     * @param $finalPrice
     * @return string
     */
    public function afterGetPrice(Product $product, $finalPrice)
    {
        if ($finalPrice === '0.000000' || $finalPrice === 0) {
            return $finalPrice = "Please call for pricing";
        } else {
            return $finalPrice;
        }
    }
}
```

The result is still $0.00

If I try to do something like `return $finalPrice + 50;` the price returns as $50.

How can I get the final price to be a string instead of $0.00?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to use plugin method same as below.

> Step 1: Please create di.xml file under path
> Company/companyplugins/etc/frontend/

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct">
        <plugin name="zealousweb_get_product_price_plugin" type="Company\companyplugins\Plugins\CallIfZero"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> Step 2: Please create file CallIfZero.php file under path
> Company/companyplugins/Plugins

```
<?php
namespace Company\companyplugins\Plugins;

use Closure;

class CallIfZero
{
    /**
     * @method aroundGetProductPrice
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct $subject
     * @param callable $proceed
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
     */
    public function aroundGetProductPrice(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct $subject,
        Closure $proceed,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
    ) {
        $result = $proceed($product);
        $finalPrice = $product->getFinalPrice();
        if ($finalPrice === '0.000000' || $finalPrice === 0) {
            return __("Please call for pricing");
        }

        return $subject->getProductPriceHtml(
            $product,
            \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice::PRICE_CODE,
            \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render::ZONE_ITEM_LIST
        );
    }
}
```

This will work according to your requirement. Please check and let me know if you have any query.

Comment: This doesn't work. I already had the correct entry in di.xml, but the issue is the same. Even if the condition is met (price is Zero), it still shows the price as $0.00 and not "Please call for pricing"

Comment: This is working for me. I can show you by screen cast as well. Which magento version you are working?

Comment: Please check - https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/3009168

Comment: In your case might be you face some confliction due to some 3rd party extension. Please check and let me know if you have any query.

Comment: I'm using the latest version 2.4.2. Might be the call for pricing plugin

Comment: I have shown you , it is from magento 2.4.1 version.

Comment: Disabling plugin after plugin. Still not working. Trying to figurer it out. Maybe it's an issue with the Porto theme